# Passing piped data to Python program and also an input file

Tags: python, file-io

I want to pass data to a Python file using a pipe and also specifying an input file like:

```
cat file.txt|python script.py -u configuration.txt
```

I currently have this:

```
for line in fileinput.input(mode='rU'):
    print(line)
```

I know there can be something with sys.argv but maybe using fileinput there is a clean way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput):

> If a filename is `'-'`, it is also replaced by `sys.stdin`. To specify an alternative list of filenames, pass it as the first argument to `input()`.

So you can create a list containing `'-'` as well as the contents of `sys.argv[1:]` (the default), and pass that to `input()`. Or alternatively just put `-` in the list of arguments of your Python program:

```
cat file.txt|python script.py -u - configuration.txt
```

or

```
cat file.txt|python script.py -u configuration.txt -
```

depending on whether you want data provided on standard input to be processed before or after the contents of `configuration.txt`.

If you want to do anything more complicated than just processing the contents of standard input as if it were an input file, you probably should not be using the `fileinput` module.